# Using XML to obtain current date

Tags: xml, dom, xsd

I'm in an XML class that has this piece of extra credit.

We are testing the date a class is added to a schedule to make sure it is on or after 9/1/1964 and before or on today's current date.

XLST Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <xs:simpleType name="DateAddedType">     
        <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">       
            <xs:minInclusive value="1964-09-01T00:00:00" />       
            <!--<xs:assert test="$value le current-date()"/>-->       
            <xs:maxInclusive value="Date.NowT00:00:00"/>     
        </xs:restriction>   
    </xs:simpleType>   

    <xs:simpleType name="DepartmentType">     
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">       
            <xs:pattern value ="[A-z]{2,5}&amp;?" />     
        </xs:restriction>   
    </xs:simpleType>    

    <xs:simpleType name ="DeptType2">     
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">       
            <xs:pattern value ="[A-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z&amp;]|[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z&amp;]" />     
        </xs:restriction>   
    </xs:simpleType>    

<xs:element name="Courses">     
    <xs:complexType>       
        <xs:sequence>         
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Course">           
                <xs:complexType>             
                    <xs:sequence>               
                        <xs:element name="Department" type="DepartmentType" />               
                        <xs:element name="CourseNumber" type="xs:string" />               
                        <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />               
                        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />               
                        <xs:element name="Credits" type="xs:unsignedByte" />               
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Prerequisites" type="xs:string" />   
                            <xs:element name="DateAdded" type="DateAddedType" />               
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Schedule">    
                                    <xs:complexType>                   
                                <xs:sequence>                     
                                    <xs:element name="Season" type="xs:string" /> 
                                                <xs:element name="Year" type="xs:string" />
                                                <xs:element name="ItemNumber" type="xs:string" />                     
                                    <xs:element name="Department" type="DepartmentType" />                     
                                    <xs:element name="CourseNumber" type="xs:string" />                     
                                    <xs:element name="Section" type="xs:string" />                     
                                    <xs:element name="Room" type="xs:string" />                     
                                    <xs:element name="MeetingDays" type="xs:string" />                     
                                    <xs:element name="StartTime" type="xs:dateTime" />                     
                                    <xs:element name="EndTime" type="xs:dateTime" />                   
                                </xs:sequence>                 
                            </xs:complexType>               
                        </xs:element>             
                    </xs:sequence>           
                </xs:complexType>         
            </xs:element>       
        </xs:sequence>     
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

The XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Courses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Courses.xsd">   
    <Course>     
        <Department>CIS</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>141</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>intro to access</Title>     
        <Description>db stuff</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <Prerequisites>108, 123</Prerequisites>     
        <DateAdded>2011-07-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>   
        <Department>cap</Department>   
        <CourseNumber>102</CourseNumber>   
        <Title>Nutrition for the Food Service Professional</Title>   
        <Description>Nutrition for the Food Service Professional</Description>   
        <Credits>5</Credits>   
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cap</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>103</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Applied Food Service Sanitation</Title>     
        <Description>Applied Food Service Sanitation</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cap</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>104</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Supervision in the Hospitality Industry</Title>     
        <Description>Supervision in the Hospitality Industry</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cis</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>145</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Introduction to access</Title>     
        <Description>Intro to access</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>     
        <Schedule>       
            <Season>Fall</Season>       
            <Year>2009</Year>       
            <ItemNumber>0000</ItemNumber>       
            <Department>cis</Department>       
            <CourseNumber>145</CourseNumber>       
            <Section>b</Section>       
            <Room>34107</Room>       
            <MeetingDays>daily</MeetingDays>       
            <StartTime>1899-12-30T08:00:00</StartTime>       
            <EndTime>1899-12-30T08:50:00</EndTime>     
        </Schedule>     
        <Schedule>       
            <Season>Winter</Season>       
            <Year>2010</Year>       
            <ItemNumber>1000</ItemNumber>       
            <Department>cis</Department>       
            <CourseNumber>145</CourseNumber>       
            <Section>d</Section>       
            <Room>34106</Room>       
            <MeetingDays>daily</MeetingDays>       
            <StartTime>1899-12-30T10:00:00</StartTime>       
            <EndTime>1899-12-30T10:50:00</EndTime>     
        </Schedule>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cis</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>160</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Introduction to Programming</Title>     
        <Description>Introduction to practices of programming</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>     
        <Schedule>       
            <Season>Winter</Season>       
            <Year>2010</Year>       
            <ItemNumber>1200</ItemNumber>       
            <Department>cis</Department>       
            <CourseNumber>160</CourseNumber>       
            <Section>e</Section>       
            <Room>34107</Room>       
            <MeetingDays>daily</MeetingDays>       
            <StartTime>1899-12-30T11:00:00</StartTime>       
            <EndTime>1899-12-30T11:50:00</EndTime>     
        </Schedule>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cis</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>245</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Applications in Access</Title>     
        <Description>Developing applications in access</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>     
        <Schedule>       
            <Season>Winter</Season>       
            <Year>2010</Year>       
            <ItemNumber>1100</ItemNumber>       
            <Department>cis</Department>       
            <CourseNumber>245</CourseNumber>       
            <Section>c</Section>       
            <Room>34128</Room>       
            <MeetingDays>daily</MeetingDays>       
            <StartTime>1899-12-30T09:00:00</StartTime>       
            <EndTime>1899-12-30T09:50:00</EndTime>     
        </Schedule>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cis</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>266</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>VB.Net Applications</Title>     
        <Description>Applications in vb.net</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>     
        <Schedule>       
            <Season>Spring</Season>       
            <Year>2010</Year>       
            <ItemNumber>3525</ItemNumber>       
            <Department>cis</Department>       
            <CourseNumber>266</CourseNumber>       
            <Section>c</Section>       
            <Room>34107</Room>       
            <MeetingDays>daily</MeetingDays>       
            <StartTime>1899-12-30T09:00:00</StartTime>       
            <EndTime>1899-12-30T09:50:00</EndTime>     
        </Schedule>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cna</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>250</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Routing and Switching</Title>     
        <Description>Introduction to Routing and Switching to design, build, and maintain small to medium-size networks.</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <Prerequisites>cna-145</Prerequisites>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cna</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>260</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Windows Scripting</Title>     
        <Description>Windows Scripting</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>   
    </Course>   
    <Course>     
        <Department>cs</Department>     
        <CourseNumber>142</CourseNumber>     
        <Title>Object Oriented Programming I</Title>     
        <Description>Object Oriented Programming I</Description>     
        <Credits>5</Credits>     
        <Prerequisites>cis-160, cis-168</Prerequisites>     
        <DateAdded>2001-03-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>   
    </Course> 
</Courses>
```

The dateAdded field is the one being tested.  Equivelant to [DateAdded >= 9/1/1964 AND DateAdded <= Today]  By utilizing the MinInclusive to test for the date in 1964, and we are to utilize maxInclusive for Today's date, but we are told to use a DTD to manipulate the schema.  Yes, it is silly to do, but since it *can* be done, the instructor wants us to do it that way.

However, he has not gone over how to do an XML file that validates through a XSLT file that uses a DTD file.  We've done a XML with DTD, and XML with XSLT, but not all three.

Comment: I guess the hint it "use DOM to manipulate the schema". That is, they want you to modify the schema itself to include the current date, before using the modified schema for validation. Though using DOM to do it is ridiculous, its clearly a job for XSLT.

Comment: I know it's ridiculous, but the instructor wants us to give it a shot.  He has us learn stuff that essentially is the hardest way, and then shows us the easier way to obtain the same thing.  Plus, this is extra credit, so he gives less hints and it's harder to solve.

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.0, there is no way of parameterizing the schema. Documents are either valid or they are not. They can't be valid today and invalid tomorrow. So there's no way of doing what you are looking for.

You can do it in XSD 1.1 using assertions: `<xs:assert test="$value le current-date()"/>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure our class is stuck with 1.0, which is why the instructor said that we had to use DOM to manipulate it.  So, from what I'm gathering, the data in the xml file is then validated by the xsl file, and the dtd file will manipulate the validation in the xsl file to obtain the current date for that one field, allowing us to use maxInclusive.  However, what to put in maxInclusive to get it to work, and the dtd file is beyond me.